# Axios POST on Gin-Gonic (golang) Server Not Working

Tags: go, axios, nuxt.js, go-gin

I can use GET, but I cannot use POST from axios, sending data to my gin-gonic golang server. It works perfectly in Postman. When I shoot over the request with Axios, I get nothing in return.

When I go into the gin-gonic server, it shows that it returned a 500 error. Upon further inspection, I see that none of the post variables had been accessed by gin.

When I have used Postman, the server returns the array as specified.  I have a feeling that it might have to do with headers, but I truly am stumped. I have encountered this problem about 6 months ago and never figured it out. Now I remember why I didn't continue with axios and nuxt :).

Here is the golang gin-gonic server route.

```
func initServer() {
    router := gin.Default()
    config := cors.DefaultConfig()
    config.AddAllowHeaders("*",)
    config.AllowAllOrigins = true
    config.AllowMethods = []string{"POST", "GET"}
    router.Use(cors.New(config))
    v1 := router.Group("/api/v1/stripe")
    {
        v1.POST("/pay", BuyProduct)
        v1.POST("/card", UpdateCard)
        v1.GET("/products", GetAllProducts)
        v1.GET("/products/id/:productId", GetProduct)
        v1.GET("/products/types/:typeId", GetProductType)
        v1.GET("/products/types", GetAllProductTypes)
    }

    // You can get individual args with normal indexing.
    serverAddress := "127.0.0.1:8080"
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        arg := os.Args[1]
        serverAddress = fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:%v", arg)
    }

    router.Run(serverAddress)
}
```

Here is the receiver function that processes the router calls when the endpoint is hit

```
func BuyProduct(c *gin.Context) {

    postUserID := c.PostForm("userId")
    postProductId := c.PostForm("productId")
    token := c.PostForm("token")

    userId, err := strconv.Atoi(postUserID)
    if err != nil {
    panic(err)
    }
    productId, err := strconv.Atoi(postProductId)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    custy := user.InitCustomer(int64(userId), token)
    custy.GetStripeCustomerData()
    custy.SelectProduct(products.NewProduct(int64(productId)))
    custy.Purchase()

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"status": 200,
        "product": custy.Product,
        "user": *custy.Saver.User,
        "subscriptions": *custy.Subscriptions,
        "ch": custy.Logs,
    })

    return
}
```

Here is my axios (nuxt) code.

```
async purchaseSubscription() {
    const paid = await 
    this.$axios.$post('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stripe/pay', { data: { 
        userId: "121",
        productId: this.productId,
    }, query: {  } })
    this.paid = paid
},
```

Here is the error I get in the gin-gonic server in go

> 2018/10/09 00:12:34 [Recovery] 2018/10/09 - 00:12:34 panic recovered:
>   POST /api/v1/stripe/pay HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:8080
>   Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 52
>   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>   Dnt: 1
>   Origin: http://localhost:3000
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Referer: http://localhost:3000/
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
>   strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:502 (0x102aca8)
>     gopanic: reflectcall(nil, unsafe.Pointer(d.fn), deferArgs(d),   uint32(d.siz), uint32(d.siz))
>   /Users/joealai/go/src/sovrin-mind-stripe/sm-stripe.go:150 (0x15f9ee5)
>     BuyProduct: panic(err)
>   [GIN] 2018/10/09 - 00:12:34 | 500 |    1.079498ms |       127.0.0.1 | POST     /api/v1/stripe/pay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is not with gin or not gin, it's just with your call. Notice that you're accessing to the `c.PostForm` values but in your axios call you're not sending a form values, you're sending a json, so in your variables the value is empty. If you're using Postman I suppose you're doing well sending a PostForm, but not in your axios. My recommendation is to still sending a Post (also add a content-type: application-json header) and `c.Bind` the body to a struct or a map[string]interface{} and then cast to your specific types in your handler.

Comment: This is the answer. I provided the final solution below. With gin-gonic, we must use the function, `c.GetRawData()`, and then unmarshal that data into a struct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no JSON POST Retrieval built into gin-gonic, and from what I understand, in Go's basic Web Server Package. Instead, we need to use c.GetRawData(), and then unmarshal the results into a struct! Since the c.GetRawData() includes `data: { userId: 121, productId: 12, token: tok_visa }`, the struct must also contain the `data` json field as well. I hope this helps someone else! Thanks @Carles

```
type Buy struct {
    Data struct {
        User    int64 `json:"userId" binding:"required"`
        Product int64 `json:"productId" binding:"required"`
        Token   string `json:"token"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

func BuyProduct(c *gin.Context) {

    a := Buy{}
    b, err := c.GetRawData()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    json2.Unmarshal(b, &a)
    userId := a.Data.User
    productId := a.Data.Product

    token := a.Data.Token
```